# Bluetooth bluegiga WT-32 не откликается

Tags: bluetooth, железо

Данный экземпляр не откликается на UART - Вообще глухо.
Пробовал на 115200, 57600, 9800

Либо со схемой что-то не то, либо инициализировать его как-то хитро нужно.
Вопрос: как получить от него реакцию на отправляемые команды?
[image: подключён так]

Answer (score 1):

Оказалось 
1)  процессор (DM3730) прижимал резет к "1". А у BT reset active HI.
2)  скорость выставить в 115200
3)  в конце команды обязательно \n или \r\n
4)  был выбран не верный com-port (uart) [В DM3730 under WinCe UARTB - оказывается = COM3]
..И вообще - нужно спать больше:D